# Azure Databricks - Library Installation Fails

Tags: azure, maven, dependencies, databricks

I am running a job from a jar file in Azure Databricks. This jar has a dependency on `azure-storage-file-share`. Previously, there wasn't an issue installing this dependency using Maven within the Databricks UI. Now, I get failure with this error message:

`Run result unavailable: job failed with error message  Library installation failed for library due to user error for maven { coordinates: "com.azure:azure-storage-file-share:12.16.2" } Error messages: Library installation attempted on the driver node of cluster 0131-144423-r1g81134 and failed. Please refer to the following error message to fix the library or contact Databricks support. Error Code: DRIVER_LIBRARY_INSTALLATION_FAILURE. Error Message: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/local_disk0/tmp/clusterWideResolutionDir/maven/ivy/jars/io.netty_netty-transport-native-kqueue-4.1.86.Final.jar does not exist`

To try to work around this, I manually installed this netty library (and several others) as well. I can see in the logs that it was able to download the jar successfully:

```
downloading https://maven-central.storage-download.googleapis.com/maven2/io/netty/netty-transport-native-kqueue/4.1.86.Final/netty-transport-native-kqueue-4.1.86.Final-osx-x86_64.jar ...  [SUCCESSFUL ] io.netty#netty-transport-native-kqueue;4.1.86.Final!netty-transport-native-kqueue.jar (202ms)
```

However, it still fails. This is error message is in the same log after the one above:

```
23/01/31 14:50:09 WARN LibraryState: [Thread 137] Failed to install library maven;azure-storage-file-share;com.azure;12.16.2;; java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/local_disk0/tmp/clusterWideResolutionDir/maven/ivy/jars/io.netty_netty-transport-native-kqueue-4.1.86.Final.jar does not exist
```

Comment: it looks like an existing bug. I would recommend to open support ticket to get estimate on when it's fixed